# Can Google Map v3 Overlays be Grouped?

Tags: arrays, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Looking through the [Google Maps Javascript v3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#RemovingOverlays) it looks like if I want to group together markers and add or remove them as groups, I need to roll my own code based on the sample below.

```
// Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array
function clearOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}

// Shows any overlays currently in the array
function showOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }
}

// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them
function deleteOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution to grouping markers and infowindows besides arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what it is you want to do, MarkerClusterer might be helpful: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html

Comment: It looks like for my problem, the best solution is to hold onto arrays of markers so I can switch "views" between all markers and directions.

This might be useful later though.  Thanks!